# Joomla creating /2-uncategorised/ page's, duplicate content?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, links, joomla

I have added some pages to a *Joomla* website (by adding articles). At first, these articles were not linked to the right menu yet. So the link was something like `example.com/2-uncategorised/25-bureau-lokeren`.

After I added the site to the right menu, the link was like it should be: `example.com/bureau-lokeren`.

When I crawled the site with *Screaming Frog*, the pages did not appear in the results anymore.

However, if I surf to the `/2-uncategorised/` links in my browser, the link still works and displays the content (even after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

So now I have 2 pages with the same content, but the wrong links do not show up in *Screaming Frog* tool (also, anyone knows why this is? I thought *Screaming Frog* finds every link on a site).

Is this just how *Joomla* works and I should not worry, or should I do something about this so Google does not penalize me for duplicate content?

Comment: When you enter `/2-uncategorised` link do you get redirected to `/bureau-lokeren` or the url remains `/2-uncategorised/`? Also are you sure you deleted the post in the `uncategorised` category?

Comment: Use canonical links and be gone with worrying...

Comment: Make sure these pages do not show up in a sitemap. This and the fact that there are no links should be good, however, you will also want to use canonical tags.

Comment: How can i edit the <head> tag for specific pages (articles)? I want to insert the rel canonical tag, but I'm not that familiar with Joomla, haven't found out how to edit head code for specific pages. I've checked the ftp but I can't find the right html/php pages there either.